# How can I capture the screenshot of an Alert in Selenium WebDriver (Java) while executing the code remotely?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, screenshot

I'm able to get the screenshot of Alert by using Robot class when the code is running from server machine (where the code is present). But its not capturing the screen when I'm trying to run through Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because your code on Jenkins is running in headless mode while Robot doesn't work in headless mode.
At least I had exactly the same problem.
You can use a `TakesScreenshot` method instead.
It is based on WebDriver and supports headless mode as well.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, But TakesScreenshot methods actually doesn't work to take the screenshot of an Alert. For taking the screenshot of something attached to the webdriver is working with TakesScreenshot method, but not for alert. Pls correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: Well, I didn't face with situation my screenshot was ever missing something. However I also don't remember there were Alerts in our test scenarios, so I can say nothing about Alerts in screenshots.